# HTTP Response - Excel file- Save to disk

Tags: c#, excel, httpresponse

I am using Excel Helper class in order to generate an excel sheet with each data table in data set as a worksheet inside excel.

I am able to get the excel with multiple worksheets,but is there any way to save this to a location directly from the code.

As the excel downloads directly when I run the code and I have to manually save it.Please advise.

```
  public static void ToExcel(DataSet dsInput, string filename, HttpResponse response)
    {
        var excelXml = GetExcelXml(dsInput, filename);
        response.Clear();
        response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
        response.Write(excelXml);
         response.Flush();
        response.End();
    }


    Using the helper class to genrate Dataset into multiple tabs //  
        try
        {

             ds = obj.Get_Tables();
        }
      ExcelHelper.ToExcel(ds, "AlertDetails.xls", Page.Response);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set `response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"` there is a fair chance that the browser will offer to save the file. The browser might inspect the start of the file and decide that it is an Excel file and, depending on what the user has chosen to do, open it anyway.

Also, you should surround the filename with double-quotes.

You *cannot* get the browser to save to a particular location - that would be open to abuse.